# C++ or C#: Which language is Microsoft going to use in development of future Windows versions?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, microsoft, operating-systems

I heard almost all parts of Windows are written in C and C++ with some assembly. Why did Microsoft skip C#? Is there any scope for C# in the development of future Windows versions?

Comment: C and C++ compile to assembly.  C# compiles to bytecode for the CLI.  This bytecode and virtual machine abstraction prevent it from being useable as a language to program an operating system that needs to talk to the hardware directly.  Whine in theory, one *could* write a C# compiler to assembly, the abstractions of the hardware in the associated runtime would still be there making it unsuitable.

Comment: @MichaelT I thought Windows accessed the hardware through the HAL? If this is the case then the only code which would need to be processor-specific is the HAL itself.

Comment: I bet they will use Java. Oh and since I am an oracle, I therefore predict they will also rename company to Oracle

Comment: @gnat Microdeck but it won't happen till 2029. Speculation about future actions of organizations or individuals is not constructive. Have a pleasant day.

Comment: @MichaelT: C, C++ and C# don't compile to anything. They are programming languages. Programming languages don't compile, compilers do. There are compilers for C and C++ that compile to JavaScript, JVM bytecode, CIL bytecode or LLVM bitcode, for example. There are even *interpreters* for C and C++. On the flipside, there are compilers for C# which compile to native code, there are also compilers which compile CIL to native code. In fact, there is no implementation of C# in actual use today that does *not* eventually compile to native code.

Answer (score 6):

C++ gives you access to the underlying hardware, something C# can't provide. So for the foreseeable future, Windows will be built in C++ (as parts as still built in assembly where raw performance and interrupt handling are necessary).

As a proof-of-concept, Microsoft Research built [Singularity](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/singularity/), a C#-based operating system. It uses a superset of C# called Spec# and some other extensions to minimize the need for C++ and other lower-level languages.

Comment: of course minimising the need for C/C++ could also be written "still has to use C/C++".

Comment: @gbjbaanb: The only reason why Singularity still uses C++, C and assembly in parts of the OS is that the OS was being written *while* Sing# was being designed, and the parts of Sing# that would have been needed to write, say, interrupt handlers hadn't been designed yet when the interrupt handlers were being written. Now that the features are there, one *could* re-write those parts in Sing#, but Singularity is a research project: showing that it *could* be written in a managed language is enough, you don't have to *actually* write it. That's the difference between engineering and research.

Comment: Another big chunk of C++ code in Singularity is the debugging interface, which is in C++ only because it was basically copy&pasted from Windows and .NET, so that the Singularity team could re-use the existing debugging tools.

Answer (score 0):

In direct answer to your question, I bet you'd find that most of Windows pre-dates C# in any case.

Who's to say what will happen in the future? I've seen so many revolutionary ideas from MS over the last 25 years that I've lost count.

But I read somewhere that VS2012 (the gui at least) was entirely rewritten in C# and WPF, so maybe you could take that as a sign of future direction? But I wouldn't put money on it.

Answer (score 0):

Not working in product development but clearly microsoft windows for good years will still be developed in C and C + +. This is because the languages ​​allow / provide access to hardware to a safe level instruction. C # runs on MSIL and has no goal of being language OS.

Comment: C# does not "run on" MSIL.  C# and all the other .NET languages are compiled to IL, which is basically a hardware-agnostic assembly language.  And of course it is also entirely possible to target IL using the C++ compiler, as well.  IL is then compiled (JIT or ngen) all the way to machine code for the hardware it is running on.  The resulting machine code still has a dependency on the .NET runtime, of course.  As of Windows Vista it was possible to write Windows device drivers using C#.  So, parts of the OS are in fact written using .NET, but it seems unlikely that the HAL will ever be .NET.

Answer (score -1):

At the time, there were no serious competitors to C/C++ in systems programming and now it's a legacy codebase that would probably cost a lot to port. C# also did not exist back then. For the record, [there are attempts](https://github.com/ProtonOS/Proton) to turn [.NET into an OS platform](http://www.mosa-project.org/projects/1/wiki/FAQ) but these are not Microsoft projects.

Comment: There's also a Microsoft attempt called Singularity: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/singularity/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(operating_system)